# Cordova + Android : How to get path to sd card?

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems, sd-card, android-sdcard

I'm trying to play some mp3 files (which app downloaded from the remote server) from sd card using Cordova.

I tried to use following:

```
 if($ionicPlatform.is('android')){
                  src = 'yourPersistantAppFolder/main_expansion/' + src;
                }
```

and

```
 if($ionicPlatform.is('android')){
                  src = 'sdcard/yourPersistantAppFolder/main_expansion/' + src;
                }
```

But without luck.

I tried to find some anwser here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

But without the luck.

Many thanks for any advice.

**Edit:**

Path in Android is displayed like this:

[image]

Comment: First you have to distinguish between the "External Storage" which is easy to find vs an "sdcard" that may or may not be the same thing, and can be tricky to to locate across vendor variations.  Then you need to figure out how cordova presents these Android APIs to you - or in the unlikely case that it does not, you will have to make your own plugin.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
(jc??? are mysupport routines)

```
import { File } from "@ionic-native/file";
import { Diagnostic } from "@ionic-native/diagnostic";

constructor(
    ...
    public file: File,
    public diagnostic: Diagnostic
){

this.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails()
.then( (data) => {
  this.jcError += "\n" + "sd:" + JSON.stringify( data);
  this.jcError += "\n" + "Number cards: " + data.length;
  for( let ii = 0; ii < data.length; ii += 1){
    let thisElem = data[ii];
    if( thisElem.type.toLowerCase() === "application" && thisElem.canWrite){
      this.ourSDentry = thisElem;
      basePathSD = thisElem.filePath;
      break;
    }
  }
  if( !basePathSD){
    this.jcError += "\n\n" + "no SD card found";
    return;
  }
}, (errData)=>{
  tag = "getExternalSdCardDetails";
  this.jcError += "\n\n" + tag + ":ERR:" + JSON.stringify( errData);
});
```